# Add "Select" For Custom Post Type Metabox

Tags: metabox

My Question is partially based on this tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-display-metaboxes-according-to-the-current-post-format--wp-27970

I'm trying to add a new "select" field. Here's what I did so far:

```
case "select":
    echo '<ul class="field"><li class="left"><label for="' . $id . '" class="' . $id . '">' . $field['title'] . '</label></li><li class="right"><select name="' . $id . '">';
        foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
            echo '<option ', $custom == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>' . $option . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></li></ul>'; break;
```

That retreives data from the following fields:

```
$prefix . 'video_type' => array(
    'title' => __('Source:', 'twentyeleven'),
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array('Youtube', 'Vimeo'),
    'description' => '',
),
```

The problem is, I can't get the data saved.

If you want to see the complete code, here it's: http://pastebin.com/Ms49508P

Comment: Anyone? I really need this help

Comment: Did you get this resolved?